# Change title of a navigation bar button item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

```
let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "coin_icon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(Profile.goCoin), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)
        button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

My code is this to add a bar button on navigation bar.

However, i need to change the title of button in a function

```
func changetitle() {
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Change"
}
```

I tried this one but didn't work.

How can i change the title of this button?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to access the `UIButton` from the `UIBarButtonItem` and change the title of the `UIButton`.

```
func changetitle() {
    let item = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!
    let button = item.customView as! UIButton
    button.setTitle("Change", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works, just need to change item to item! and as to as!

Comment: `button.setTitle("Change", for:.normal)`
 you forgot the , and it has changed to normal in lowercase

Comment: @famfamfam Please post your own question showing all relevant code and details about what is happening and what should be happening.